# for (let .. of ) error in grunt build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have an Angular aplication and in some controller have the following code:

```
for (let subForm of $scope.info.subForms) {
    var index = $scope.data.fields.indexOf(subForm);
    $scope.data.subForms.push($scope.data.fields.splice (index + 1 , (subForm.data * subForm.filesLength)));
};
......
```

when run my aplication using `grunt serve` the aplication run normal without errors but when generete the deploy code using the command `grunt build` get the following error:

```
Unexpected token name «subForm», expected punc «;». 
Line 1410 in .tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js
Use --force to continue.
```

is a grunt error? I have `grunt v0.4.5`
thanks for your help

**EDIT**

In the following link [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) could see documentation about the syntax

Comment: What is grunt serve?

Comment: By the way let is es6 syntax.

Comment: This looks like a syntax error in the JS produced. Can you post the part of your `Gruntscript` which does the building and serving? There may be a difference in the target they are compiling to.

Comment: why there is a space after `indexOf` in `var index = $scope.data.fields.indexOf (subForm);`?

Comment: HI @Yerken it was a mistake but it was not the reason for the error Grunt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try using this

```
angular.foreach($scope.info.subForms, function(subForm) {
    var index = $scope.data.fields.indexOf (subForm);
    $scope.data.subForms.push($scope.data.fields.splice (index + 1 , (subForm.data * subForm.filesLength)));
})
```

Your inside code maybe can need a refactor. If you share the use, I can try help you.

#### Another solution

```
for (let index = 0; index < subForm of $scope.info.subForms.length; index++) {
    $scope.data.subForms.push($scope.data.fields.splice (index + 1 , (subForm.data * subForm.filesLength)));
};
```

Comment: Work, grunt means that does not support the notation for (let .. of ..)?

Comment: Can you send me some documentation about that? I can't find information like your example.

Comment: I added link in the question

Answer (score -1):

This just seem to be a error because of space between `indexOf` and `(`. Change your code as below:

```
for (let subForm of $scope.info.subForms) {
  var index = $scope.data.fields.indexOf(subForm);
  $scope.data.subForms.push($scope.data.fields.splice(index + 1 , (subForm.data * subForm.filesLength)));
};
```

The error is also pointing to an expected `;` which means that its considering the space to be end of this statement and prompting for a `;`